# Analytic continuation of $f(x)=\sqrt{\frac{1-x}{1-x^p}}$ over the p-adics

Tags: nt.number-theory, p-adic-analysis, p-adic-numbers

Consider the power series $f(x)=\sqrt{\frac{1-x}{1-x^p}}$ over the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}_p$, defined by $f(0)=1$. 
What can be said about an analytic continuation "in the form of Mittag-Leffler"? By that I mean that $f(x)$ can be expressed as
$f(x)=g(x)+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{a_n(x)}{h(x)^n}$, where $g(x)$ converges in a disk greater than the unit ball, $h(x)$ is a polynomial of norm $\le 1$, and the $a_n(x)$ are polynomials satisfying $\text{ord}_p(a_n)\ge rn-m$ for some $r>0$ and a constant $m \in \mathbb{R}$. Here the order of a polynomial is the minimum order of its coefficients.

I am particuarly interested in the values $f(\lambda)$, for Teichmuller representatives $\lambda$, which satisfy $\lambda^q=\lambda$ for some $q=p^r$. Thus I would like $h(x)$ not to have a zero at the Teichmuller representatives. Apparently the values at the Teichmuller representatives are related to classical results on Gauss Sums but I couldn't find anything in the literature.

Comment: By "analytic continuation", you mean that the power series converges also outside the unit ball, or analytic in the sense of Krasner?

Comment: @EFinat-S, I have clarified what I mean by analytic continuation, I think it corresponds to the latter.

Comment: Ok, that makes an important difference. I'll delete my answer.

Comment: Sorry for another question:  is the condition $\operatorname{ord}_p(a_n) \ge r n$ a condition on some coefficient of $a_n(x)$, all coefficients of $a_n(x)$, some value of $a_n(x)$, or all coefficients of $a_n(x)$, or is it something else?

Comment: I don't know if this will help you, but the book "Analytic elements in $p$-adic analysis" by Alain Escassut has a chapter called "Composition of anaytic elements". Perhaps this is useful since you are composing an analytic function with a rational function.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense because $f(\zeta_p+p x)$ is not meromorphic at $0$

Comment: @reuns the sum is an infinite sum of rational functions, so I don't see where is the problem.